# When listing of objects using the IBM Cloud Object Storage CLI, and also in my Java program, I get a TLS handshake error

Tags: amazon-s3, websphere, ibm-cloud, trigonometry, tls1.2

I can list my buckets in the COS CLI:

```
ibmcloud cos buckets     
OK

2 buckets found in your account:

Name                                       Date Created   
cloud-object-storage-kc-cos-standard-8e7   May 20, 2020 at 14:40:37   
cloud-object-storage-kc-cos-standard-nw6   Dec 14, 2020 at 16:35:48
```

But if I try to list the objects in the second bucket I get the following:

```
ibmcloud cos objects -bucket cloud-object-storage-kc-cos-standard-nw6 -region us-east 
FAILED
RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Get https://cloud-object-storage-kc-cos-standard-nw6.s3.us-east.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

I do not know why I would get a TLS handshake error on such a call.  If I try any other region, I get a "The specified bucket was not found in your IBM Cloud account. This may be because you provided the wrong region. Provide the bucket's correct region and try again."

```
My Cloud Object Storage configuration is (X's are redacted data):
Last Updated            Tuesday, December 15 2020 at 11:16:46   
Default Region          us-geo   
Download Location       /Users/xxxxxx@us.ibm.com/Downloads   
CRN                     b6cc5f87-5867-4736-XXXX-cf70c34a1fb7   
AccessKeyID                
SecretAccessKey            
Authentication Method   IAM   
URL Style               VHost   
Service Endpoint
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the exact location of your COS bucket, you can try running the below command

```
ibmcloud cos buckets-extended
```

> buckets-extended: List all the extended buckets with pagination support.

Pass the `Location Constraint` for the bucket in the below command

```
ibmcloud cos objects --bucket vmac-code-engine-bucket --region us-standard
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I ran:  
ibmcloud cos buckets-extended
Found 2 buckets:
Name                                       Location Constraint   Creation Date   
cloud-object-storage-kc-cos-standard-8e7   us-east-standard 
cloud-object-storage-kc-cos-standard-nw6   us-east-smart

Then I ran:
ibmcloud cos objects --bucket cloud-object-storage-kc-cos-standard-nw6 --region us-east-smart   
FAILED MissingEndpoint: 'Endpoint' configuration is required for this service

Do you know where I enter the 'Endpoint'?

Comment: IBM Cloud Object Storage CLI requires configuration before running any other commands. Follow the instructions here to configure the endpoint-url https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-cli-plugin-ic-cos-cli#ic-config